# Does Linux run on the Raspberry Pi?

Tags: linux, raspberry-pi

I was looking to get acquainted with Linux and I didn't want to install it onto my school laptop. However, I have 2 raspberry pis and I was wondering if they actually ran Linux and if there were any introductory things I could do to get familiar with Linux.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes they do run Linux! You can download images for SD cards from [Raspberry PI site](http://www.raspberrypi.org/downloads).

Comment: I am currently running raspbian. Other than messing around inside the terminal are there any other things I could do to get better acquainted with Linux? @grzegorz

Comment: @indieDev, "messing around inside the terminal" is a big portion of what "getting acquainted" with linux is all about.  That said, if you want a fuller view of linux you might want to just run linux in a VM on your laptop.